# How to stop / pause webcamera

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, webrtc

I need to close access to the webcam from the browser tab which has localvideo. Im using this for video conference app and need to pause the localvideo

```
    async getUserMedia() {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      try {
        let constraints;
          constraints = { 'video': true, 'audio': true };
          const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
          this.localStream = stream;
          this.localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
          this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error getting user media.', err);
      }
    }

    else {
      console.log('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
    }
  }
```

I tried with this, but its just stop the video and wont cannot connect again with the users

```
    export async function camera(e) {
  var stream = localVideo.srcObject;
  var tracks = stream.getTracks();

  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    var track = tracks[i];
    track.stop();
  }

  localVideo.srcObject = null;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @IanKemp, I tried with `stream.stop()` but looks like it is not working now. And i tried with changing the value for `constraints = { 'video': false, 'audio': true };` however its just stop showing the feed to the client but still sending the feed to other users

Comment: i have update the option which i used

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
//for disable
  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    var track = tracks[i];
    track.enabled = false;
  }

//for enable

  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    var track = tracks[i];
    track.enabled = false;
  }
```